# Scale-Invariant DGHV Scheme - Decryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I have just started reading the Scale-Invariant [Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/032.pdf) paper and I'm a bit confused about something:

When decrypting the ciphertext:

$c = r + (m+2r^*) \cdot \frac{p-1}{ 2} + q \cdot p^2$

using the decryption function `m = (2c mod p) mod 2`, I get $-m$ instead of $m$. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ... You're apparently implementing ​ mod 2 ​ wrong, since that should output a non-negative number. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The only valid values for m are $0$ and $1$. So are you getting $0$ and $-1$? Note that $-1\equiv 1 \bmod{2}$.